# Which row does MySQL naturally "choose" when doing a GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql, sql

How does MySQL decide which row's value to use when grouping?

```
id |  type |     timestamp
-------------------------------
1  |   3   | 2014-09-10 17:03:43
2  |   7   | 2014-09-10 17:15:00
3  |   18  | 2014-09-10 17:17:55
4  |   9   | 2014-09-10 18:01:30
5  |   18  | 2014-09-10 18:02:29
6  |   3   | 2014-09-10 18:06:26
7  |   3   | 2014-09-10 18:06:30
```

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable GROUP BY type
```

This has implications where the timestamp is concerned.

Does it use the first one, the last, something determined via internal workings?

Comment: This is what you are looking for: [MySQL Extensions to GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html)

Comment: If it has implications, don't let mysql choose.  Write your query in such a way that it's your choice.

Comment: @DanBracuk I always do. I was hoping MySQL had a way of not forcing me to write slow subqueries to do something simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without aggregate functions(`MIN,MAX,SUM` etc.) on the columns not in `GROUP BY`,mysql will return *indeterminate* values.In other databases this is not even allowed.

> The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they
>   are the same, the values chosen are [indeterminate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html)

However you can enable [ONLY FULL GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) mode.

Comment: That's what I thought. Stupid.